# Группировка sql запроса по максимальному значению №2

Tags: sql

Есть

Таблица Zadolgnosti

- Zachetka
- lekcii
- praktika
- moduli
- nomer

Таблица SpisokZadolgnostey

- DisciplinaID
- Semester
- Data
- Kurs
- Potok
- Nomer

Приходят данные, например, что на 1 курс, 1 поток студенты имеют задолжности по дисциплине DisciplinaID. Я добавляю, что будет исчисление по данной дисциплине за семестр у студентов 1 курса... потока, и присваивается автоинкрементом номер(nomer). Потом выставляются задолджности, например, иванов получил задолжность за  1 октября по алгебре 20 часов по практике, 10 по лекц, и не сдал 1 модуль и т.д. Потом приходят данные уже, например, на 1 декабря по тому же предмету... и т.д. Фактически данные более старой даты уже не действительны, но они есть(как архив) и мне надо вывести задолжности у иванова самой новой даты по дисциплине, (или не выводить их вообще если исчисление есть за более новую дату, а у него задолжностей нет, т.е. какбы считается что он сдал всё). Мне надо узнать дисциплины с самой последней датой, точнее номера...(с where kurs=1 and potok=1 and semester=1) из Spisokzadolgnostey, потом перебрать в задолжностях данные номера и посмотреть задолжности у Zachetka (Иванова), и вывести что у Иванова такие то задолжности (а если были задолжности за старую дату по предмету, а есть новая по этому же предмету и Иванова в списке нет(т.е. сдал всё), то их выводить не надо).

Comment: oracle mysql postgresql sql

странные метки, ище было бы интересно на чем человек пишет если и мускул и постгрес юзаются.

Там наверное натовская БД.

Comment: )))) а это я для того что б больше вероятность была, что зайдут сюда...

Comment: Ко всем перечисленным нет.

А вероятность захода, это уже вероятность. "дедов" тут немного и не все смотрят темы. А новички просто так просматривают.

Comment: @Роман Ракзин Если вы будете оформлять вопрос качественно (вместо того, чтобы указывать не относящиеся к вопросу метки), вероятность получить ответ вырастет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select Z.zachetka,Z.praktika,Z.lekcii,Z.moduli,SpisokNomerovSPoslednimiDatami.nomer,SZ1.Disciplina,SZ1.data from Zadolgnosti Z inner join 
(select SZ.nomer from SpisokZadolgnostey SZ
INNER JOIN
(select max(data) max_data,disciplina from SpisokZadolgnostey where Yearnumber=1 and kurs=1 and potok=1 and forma='false' group by disciplina ) SpisokPoslednihDat
on SpisokPoslednihDat.Disciplina=SZ.Disciplina and SpisokPoslednihDat.max_data=SZ.data) SpisokNomerovSPoslednimiDatami
on SpisokNomerovSPoslednimiDatami.nomer=Z.nomer
inner join SpisokZadolgnostey SZ1 on SZ1.nomer=SpisokNomerovSPoslednimiDatami.nomer
```